# IndexError: list index out of range and adding column from diffrent dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe

How to remove

> "IndexError: list index out of range" Error

```
import yaml
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

'''Get All the file_names into List'''

all_files=glob.glob('D:\\Dbda\\Project\\Data_Cleaning\\Test_Data\\*.yaml')
file_count=0
all_stats_list=[]
all_score_list=[]

'''Get Only Statistics Data into Stat DataFrame'''

for file_name in all_files:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        file_count += 1
        print(file_count)
        df_stats = pd.io.json.json_normalize(yaml.load(f))
        all_stats_list.append(df_stats)
        print(all_stats_list)

df_all_stats=pd.concat(all_stats_list)
df_all_stats=df_all_stats[df_all_stats.columns.difference(['innings'])]
df_all_stats.drop(columns=['meta.created','meta.data_version','meta.revision'],inplace=True)
'''df_all_stats.columns=['city', 'date', 'gender', 'match_type',
       'outcome.by.runs', 'outcome.winner', 'overs',
       'player_of_match', 'teams', 'decision',
       'winner', 'umpires', 'venue']
'''
df_all_stats.to_csv('final1.0Stats.csv')


'''Get only Innings_Score Data into Innings_Score Dataframe'''
file_count=0
for file_name in all_files:
    file_count += 1
    print(file_count)
    d = yaml.load(open(file_name))
    for i in d['innings']:
        df_scores = pd.DataFrame(i[list(i.keys())[0]])
        df_scores = pd.io.json.json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(df_scores.deliveries.tolist()).stack().tolist()).assign(team=df_scores.team,date=df_scores['info.dates'])
        all_score_list.append(df_scores)

df_all_scores=pd.concat(all_score_list)
df_all_scores.to_csv('final1.0Scores.csv')
```

I want to add date_column in dataframe "df_all_scores", where data column will be taken from other dataframe "df_all_stats".
the both of the innings from the match file should have a column date. 
and for optimization, I am thinking on lines of merging both those or loops and then from "df_all_stats" put date column into "df_all_scores".

CSV files are in 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=13MfFmlQFPo1Dl0ixA1mAkTliJOfqqOYH

Comment: Your yamll files?

Comment: Check now on drive.

Comment: It is working on my system properly. Can you post the exact error with line number.

Comment: Please see updated problem statement for reference. Thanx